# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError on Maven multi module project using Spring

Tags: java, maven, spring-mvc

I work on a maven multi module project with submodules. I use Spring and Spring MVC

```
 <modules>
   <module>web</module>
   <module>business</module>
   <module>integration</module>
   <module>persistence</module>
   <module>common</module>
   <module>logging</module>
</modules>
```

I want to get data from my view to controller using Jackson

```
@RequestMapping(value = "registerAgency", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public final String 
registerAgency(@RequestBody final RealEstateAgency realEstateAgency) {

//doSmth();
return "index";
}
```

My controller is in my web module and my RealEstateAgency class is in common module
When I run my project I get the following errors

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet.init() for servlet dispatcher threw exception
org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/ss/ita/redplatform/common/entity/RealEstateAgency
java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2625)
java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1868)
org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:609)
org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:521)
org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:507)
org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.determineCandidateConstructors(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:241)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineConstructorsFromBeanPostProcessors(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1069)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1042)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:772)
org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:839)
org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:538)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:668)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:634)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:682)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:553)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:494)
org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:160)
org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Can anyone tell me what i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You probably just need to add a dependency on your `common` module to your `pom.xml` in your `web` module

Comment: It is done. There are dependencies between modules. The problem is in @RequestBody. When I don't use it there are no exceptions

Comment: Maybe you have some static initialization in your `RealEstateAgency` class that is throwing an Exception?

Comment: Also, when you build, make sure you're doing a `mvn clean install` from your top level project to ensure that your `web` module is pulling the most recent version of your class from the `common` module.